# How to Display Modified Time and Modified By Fields Correctly with Powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime, sharepoint-2010, version, modified-date

I have a script that outputs to CSV all items/files from all Lists and Libraries. In addition, it displays the current and previous versions of an item/file. This also displays which user modified the file for each version and also displays the date/time the file was modified for every version:

```
function Get-DocInventory([string]$siteUrl) {
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://contoso.com/sites/Depts3/HBG"
foreach ($list in $web.Lists) {


foreach ($item in $list.Items) {
foreach($version in $item.Versions){
$data = @{
"Version" = $version.VersionLabel
"List Name" = $list.Title
"Created By" = $item["Author"]
"Created Date" = ($item["Created"] -as [datetime]).DateTime
"Modified By" = $version["Editor"]
"Modified Date" = ($version["Modified"] -as [datetime]).DateTime
"Item Name" = $item.Name

}
New-Object PSObject -Property $data | Select "List Name", "Item Name", "Version", "Created By", "Created Date", "Modified By", "Modified Date"
}
}
$web.Dispose();
}
}




Get-DocInventory  | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\GenerateReport.csv
```

Below is a sample of what the script outputs:

[image]

And below is an excel example of what I see when I go to the Version History of the Lions.pdf file:

[image]

I have 2 problems:

- The column Modified By is displaying email and domain username which is not required.
- My script displays the column Modified Date as 5 hours ahead. The script output for Version 1 of Lions.pdf displays time as 11:23 AM. But when I go to Version History of Lions.pdf it says that Version 1 was modified at 6:23 AM. The time discrepancy is the same across the board as 5 hours ahead which is incorrect.

I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong here. Can someone please assist in the issue I am having? My main concern is the time and I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Comment: What is your local time offset?

Comment: My machine says (UTC-07:00) Arizona. Is that the information you need?

Comment: You run this code on your local system or on remote?

Comment: Does `"Modified By" = $version["Editor"]` return a string or an object?  If an object, pull just the property you want.  If it is a string, use regex to strip off the part following ,#.  The timestamp is probably different because the time zone is different between where you're viewing the date and where you're running the script.  One of the systems has a different timezone.

Comment: This is on a local machine.

Comment: Sorry I'm assisting with someone and not too savvy with PS. Can someone show me with a script?

Comment: Try `"Modified By" = $version.createdby` and `"Modified Date" = $version.created.datetime` and see if those get you what you want.

Comment: I tried changing to "Modified By" = $version.createdby and "Modified Date" = $version.created.datetime and the Modified By column returns blank and the Modified Date returns time 5hrs ahead:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**User Fields**

Normally in server side code, accessing a user field value using array notation (eg `myItem["Author"]`) would return an object that you would cast to an appropriate type (`Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUserValue`). Powershell, however, automatically casts these values to strings, which is why you're getting undesirable values.

Fortunately, there's a way around it! First, get the field itself as an object, then pass the field value into the field's `GetFieldValue()` method.

```
$userField = $item.Fields.GetField("Author");
$authorObject = $userField.GetFieldValue($item["Author"]);
```

You'll then have an object with properties you can access to retrieve the desired values, such as `LookupValue` for the user's display name on the site.

```
$authorName = $authorObject.LookupValue;
```

**Date Fields**

Date fields are little easier, because Powershell will actually hand them over to you as DateTime objects.

To format a DateTime object, you can just call `.ToString()` and pass in a parameter indicating the desired format.

```
$data = @{
    ...
    "Modified Date" = $item["Modified"].ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt");
    ...
}
```

**Time Discrepancy**

This is most likely attributable to your local timezone. The times displayed on a SharePoint site via the browser are determined by your PC's timezone settings. The times actually saved to SharePoint's underlying database are determined by the server's timezone settings.

<strike>To reconcile them, you can use the DateTime object's `.ToUniversalTime()` method to get a corresponding DateTime object in UTC time (and optionally offset it as desired until it aligns with the local timezone and daylight savings adjustments).</strike>

**Edit:** I'm guessing you're in US Eastern time (UTC-5) and it's giving you results in UTC time (Universal Coordinated Time, which is 5 hours ahead of you except during daylight saving time). You should be able to offset the hours manually to account for this.

```
$localOffset = -5;
$modified = $version["Modified"] -as [datetime];
if($modified.IsDaylightSavingTime()){$localOffset += 1;}
$modifiedLocal = $modified.addHours(-$localOffset);
```

Comment: I was able to return user name much cleaner thanks to your help. The only discrepancy now is the Time. How or where would I append .ToUniversalTime() in the script to solve the problem of time returning 5 hrs ahead for the Modified Date column? Could you please clarify for me?

Comment: I've updated my answer with some example code for manually offsetting the time. The `ToUniversalTime()` function would be useful for converting a local time to UTC time, but in your case I think you want to do the opposite.